# Animate.css plugin not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the animate.css plugin, which was supposed to be a simple task but I just couldn't get it to work. Where have I gone wrong? This is my code (as simple as it is):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      .demo{
        background-color:red;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        margin:300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="demo animated bounce"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have saved both the animate.css and the code up top at my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your code, the *"animate.css"* file is supposed to be in a folder called *"css"*, relative to where the .html file is located.

So, if your .html file is on the desktop, you have two options:

1. Create a folder on your desktop, called *"css"* and move *"animate.css"* into that folder, or...
2. Edit your code to point to the correct location of the file:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
   ```

Comment: changing the directory worked but `<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">` didnt work out. Even though thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your file structure might not sorted as of now. Use the CDN version of "animate.css"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
```

Here is a link to a fiddle for the same.

```css
.demo{
background-color:red;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
<div class="demo animated bounce"></div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.